# Using IMAP in Java, Need better performance

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

We are using Javax packages to create IMAP connection. As of now we are connecting to Gmail servers .

For establishing connection it's taking around 4 seconds. Is there any way to reduce the time while creating a connection ??

following is the sample code to create connection

```
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.setProperty("mail.store.port", 993);

        // IMAPStore connection pool
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectionpoolsize", "1");
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.connectionpooltimeout", "300000");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
        IMAPStore store = (IMAPStore) session.getStore("imap");

    **UPDATED ON 5/01/2017**

    /*gmail account connection through javamail api*/ 

 Properties props = System.getProperties();         props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null); Store store = session.getStore("imaps"); store.connect("imap.gmail.com","example@gmail.com","example1‌​‌​23");

 /*host connection*/ 

    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = new InetSocketAddress("imap.gmail.com", 993);
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) socketFactory.createSocket();
    socket.connect(remoteAddress);
```

The host connection is taking 0.8 seconds.In JavaMail API SSLSocket is already used.so how can this modification of SSLSocket connection  be used in JavaMail API,in other words how can this SSLSocket object used in Store object for connection of gmail.

Comment: Keep the connection openned for the whole session?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot give exhaustive advice. I just remember we once had such a performance problem that was mysterious to us and where no one could find the cause until someone had the idea that it did not have to do anything with our implementation but with network and/or DNS settings. If I remember correctly, each attempt to establish a connection resulted in a reverse lookup. This took several seconds on one server, and finished immediately on others. I think it was something like first lookup did not work and got a timeout, then fallback worked. Perhaps worth looking into the net config.

Comment: You should enable DEBUG output for the connection handling and check the timestamps to find the slow part.

Comment: The slowness could be in the host name lookup before the connection even starts, in the actual socket connection going through your firewall, or in the SSL processing while looking up and verifying certificates.  You're going to need to do some debugging to figure out which part is slow.  You can eliminate JavaMail from the equation and just create an SSLSocket connection to help isolate the slowness.

Comment: As per @BillShannon suggestion I have tried this approach,                     I have used SSLSocketFactory and SSLSocket classes to connect to the imap.gmail.com host.But I need to connect to particular mail account like it is done through java mail Session and Store classes.Could you please suggest how to incorporate SSLSocketFactory and Store.

Comment: /*gmail account connection through javamail api*/                       Properties props = System.getProperties(); props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps"); Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null); Store store = session.getStore(); store.connect("imap.gmail.com","example@gmail.com","example1‌​23"); /*host connection*/                                                          SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = ( SSLSocketFactory ) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();                                 SSLSocket socket = ( SSLSocket ) socketFactory.createSocket( "imap.gmail.com", 993 );

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear.  The point of using SSLSocket was so that you could determine how long it took to connect and could narrow the problem down to things unrelated to JavaMail.  Note that you need to do more than just create the socket, you also have to connect it.  Once you solve your performance problem (which is almost certainly unrelated to JavaMail), JavaMail will benefit from that solution as well since it just uses SSLSocket itself.  You'll eventually need JavaMail to actually read the email at Gmail.

Comment: @BillShannon Thanks for your help. I have updated the code section.Kindly look into it and suggest what can be done after this socket connection.

Comment: If it takes SSLSocket .8 seconds to connect and it takes JavaMail 4 seconds to connect, the additional time is probably the time it takes the server to authenticate your username and password.  You would need to do more detailed profiling of the code to determine exactly what's taking so long.  There are lots of ways to do this profiling.  Your IDE might be able to help you; I would start there.  Or you can use java.util.logging to get timestamped log messages from JavaMail showing in more detail what it's doing.  That will help you figure out what's taking all the time.

Comment: Also, add "socket.startHandshake();" after the socket.connect call in your code and see if that changes the timing at all.

Comment: I  used startHandshake it took 1~1.5 seconds. The overall time of my inbox which includes connection and fetching of mails is around 5 seconds. I had tried with setDebug() previously,to my observation connecting the host and as you said authentication was taking time.But surely I will try with  java.util.logging.Thanks alot.

Comment: If most of the time is waiting for the remote server to authenticate you, there's not much you can do to speed that up.  But, as suggested above, you can keep the connection open longer and reuse it for multiple operations.  How easy and effective this is depends a lot on exactly how you're using JavaMail.  If you're accessing multiple folders for a single user, be sure to close the folders you're not using and perhaps increase the connection pool size.  If you're dealing with multiple users, each user will need a separate connection and separate authentication so there's not much you can do.